# Slide in from left toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

I'm trying to create this slide in from right menu in my Shopify store. I can open and close the div with the use of slideToggle(), but when I try to add some other features or effects, it simply wont work.

I have tried something like this aswell:

```
.toggle('slide', direction: 'right', 500)
```

Also, I would like the hide function to work if you click outside the #sign div. Anybody know a feature that enables me to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sign").hide();
    $(".login-show1").show();

    $('.login-show1').click(function(){
        $("#sign").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>

<a class="login-show1">SIGN IN</a>
<div id="sign">
   <div id="exit" href="#" class="login-show1">x</div>
   Here is sign in form
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/ Look at this link.

Comment: Thanks @ShukhratRaimov But I don't undertsand how I could use this when the link to open the div is not next to the open div button..

Answer (score 2):

For the below code to work, you must include `jQuery UI`

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Change your script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sign").hide();
    $(".login-show1").show();


    $(".login-show1").on("click", function() {
        var slided = false;

        $(document).on('click', function(){
            $('#sign').toggle('slide', {direction:'left'}, 700);
            slided = !slided;
            if(!slided) {
                $(document).off('click');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: JQuery Ui added to head and script has been changed. The sign div can be opened by using the .login-show1 button, but there is no sliding and it can not be closed again using .login.show1 @kums

Comment: Can you provide link to the entire HTML you are using?

Comment: Include jQuery UI after you include jQuery. The order is important.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. But there apprease to be another problem. If i have other "menus" that is going to slide in from right, it interfears with each other. http://jsfiddle.net/2ppL5obk/

Might have something to do with the 'click', function()

I also realized that if I click anywhere on the page before I have even opened the div, the div opens.

@kums

Comment: I have made a change to my original answer. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.login-show1').click(function(){
    $('#myDiv').toggle('slide', {direction : right}, 500, function () {
        // callback when animation completed, add other effect here
    });
});

$('#myDiv').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').click(function(){
    /* 
    hide $('#myDiv') with:
    - $('myDiv').hide()
    or
    - $('#myDiv').toggle('slide', {direction : left})
    */
});
```